# How to return multiple values(insert sp) in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and I want to calling procedure in Java and use as web service. I have been multiple operations, "deger"  return a single value, how to return multiple values ? Happy coding

```
My procedure : 



 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE thkk_kaydet(
           p_no IN TEMP_TAHAKKUK_AG.ABONENO%TYPE,
           p_tplm IN TEMP_TAHAKKUK_AG.TOPLAM%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TEMP_TAHAKKUK_AG ("ABONENO", "TOPLAM")
      VALUES (p_no, p_tplm);
      COMMIT;
    END;
```

My web service class - with connection method

```
 import javax.jws.WebService;
    import java.sql.CallableStatement;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javax.jws.WebMethod;



    @WebService
    public class WSWebLogic {
        public static Connection getConnection_test() throws Exception {
            String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@00.00.0.00:1521:TEST";
            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";
            Class.forName(driver); // load Oracle driver
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            return conn;
          }


       @WebMethod
            public static void get_tatil (@WebParam(name = "arg0") String p_no, int p_tplm) {
                    Connection conn=null;
                    Statement stmt=null;
                    ResultSet rs=null; 
                    String deger=null;
                    try {
                      conn = getConnection_test();
                      String query = "BEGIN" +
                                        "thkk_kaydet('" +
                          p_no +
                              "','" +
                                  p_tplm +
                                      "');" +
                                "END";
                      stmt = conn.createStatement();
                      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                      while (rs.next()) {
                        deger = rs.getString(1);                        
                      }         
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    } finally {
                      try {
                        rs.close();
                        stmt.close();
                        conn.close();
                      } catch (SQLException e) {
                          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                     }          
                  }                
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare return list or array of string.

You can use List of string like this:

```
 List<String> degerList = new ArrayList();
```

when you are iterating over the array, keep filing the list as

```
       degerList.add(deger);
```

and return this `degerList`

Change the return type to `List<String>` instead of `void`

Comment: Thanks but i need to insert in oracle (p_no and p_tplm columns)  via java web services they must be separately as p_no and p_tplm columns.

Comment: return as json , parse the json and insert on the other database @M.Telceken

Comment: i added as answers, Can you help me ? Tnx a lot  @Danyal Sandeelo

Answer (score 0):

when i wrote function instead of procedure, it compiled.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function ilce_gtr
(
    p_ilkodu number  
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
 p_geridonen varchar2(1000);
begin
for rec in(SELECT ADI FROM ILCE WHERE Y_IL=p_ilkodu)
loop
p_geridonen := p_geridonen || '|' || rec.ADI;
end loop;
return p_geridonen;
end;
/
```

then i created xml via web method, it was successful.

```
  @WebMethod
        public String get_ilce (int p_ilkodu) {

            Statement stmt=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            Connection conn=null;
            String deger=null;

            try {
              conn= getConnection_test();
              String query = "SELECT ILCE_GTR('" + p_ilkodu + "') FROM DUAL";
              stmt = conn.createStatement();
              rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
              while (rs.next()) {
               deger = rs.getString(1);                        
              }        

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "hata";
            } finally {
              try {
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                return "hata";
              }          
            }            
            return deger;
        }
```

insert to oracle database using web service, how can I do it? thank u